# How to navigate back to main activity without a button

Tags: java, android

I'm accustomed to using an intent to launch a new activity when a button is pressed.

But the app that I'm making uses a list view, which means I want to be able to go back from my searching activity to the main activity by using the phone's back button.

I was reading and experimenting with different types of android methods, this one in particular which seemed simple but doesn't work, or perhaps I'm doing something completely different.

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(setIntent); 
    finish();
}
```

Doesn't Android's onBackPressed method respond to any android phone's back button?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call super.onBackPressed() inside onBackPressed() method, you dont need to start a new intent to go back.

In your search activity override the onBackPressed() method and call it from wherever you want in the activity.

it should be like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply geekoraul. I've created that method in my search activity, but whenever i want to go back to the main activity on my samsung s3 mini, it doesn't let me :(